# How to uniquely identify an NFC Reader from other NFC Readers?

Tags: nfc, uniqueidentifier, lib-nfc

> Using NFC Reader ACR122U
>
> Installed libnfc from here [link1](http://chocolatechips.me/how-to-raspberry-pi-rfid-reader-kiosk-acr122u/)
>
> Running an Attendance Project on Raspberry Pi 2 using python, mysql [on github](https://github.com/davidcdupuis/nfcattendancelogger/issues/1) .

**What do I want to achieve?**

> I WANTED TO MONITOR THE USER when they scan from the NFC Reader

**Explaining in details**
**Case Scenario:**
let's say you had 10 NFC readers in a company,
how would you programmatically differentiate an NFC reader from another especially if the user scanned their tag?

**database querying: solution!?**
I was thinking querying user's profile data. for example, if you scan, your name, Id and time of scan will be added in a mysql table. I am still struggling on how to Identify the NFC reader in this mysql table field example.

Here is how regex is able to uniquely identify the NFC tags:

```
uid = re.search(r'((\w){2}\s\s){4}',output).group(0).strip().split(" ")
 
uid = ' '.join(uid).upper()
```

Is there a way to distinguish NFC Readers from other readers?

Thank you

Comment: Each nfc reader has its own connection - use the information about the connection to record which reader read a particular tag

Comment: Sorry, but your description and your code are not sufficient to base a good advise on them. We have basically not information on your readers and the architecture.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you, the needed information is provided

Comment: +barny how would I get the information connection of the nfc reader ? Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ACR122U is an older reader and doesn't have any uniquely identifiable data fields for you to discover in software. So if you're expecting to be able to move the reader from host device to host device you won't be able to verify which one it is. If you plan on having the reader parked on one host device during it's entire usage, then you can seek out uniquely identifiable data on the host device to solve your problem. But that's a separate question.

There are newer devices from ACS like the ACR35 and the ACR1255U-J1 that do include uniquely identifiable data fields in their firmware. These can be queried in software from a host device like a PC or a smartphone. We are authorized distributors of ACS products as well as from other manufacturers. You can check out our line of NFC readers here:

http://flomio.com/product-category/readers/

We provide extensive support for these readers on [our forums](http://flomio.com/ask-the-flomies) including sample apps and development kits to help you get going quickly.

Comment: thank you very much. I did not know that. now I even consider buying estimote beabvon

Comment: Estimate beacons to achieve indoor navigation system